# Liferay Webform portlet, pass information with custom hidden field

Tags: java, webforms, liferay, portlet

I'm using Liferay 5.2.3 and i have a problem with webformportlet: I want to send a value in a CSS hidden field to be processed by webformportlet.java, like this:

view.jsp

```
<div>
    <input type="text" value="vacío" id="<portlet:namespace />ocult" name="<portlet:namespace />ocult" style="display:none" />

</div>
```

And trying to print the value of the hidden field in:

WebFoemPortlet.java

```
String oculto=ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, "ocult");

    System.out.println("CAMP OCULT: "+oculto);
```

But i get no value in "oculto" variable.

Any help will be very appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check your input tag is inside form tag.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<aui:input cssClass="" label="" type="text" name="ocult" value="vacío" />
```

then it should return the value.

Comment: FYI: aui:input tag automatically adds portlet-namespace before name or id. so no need to specify it separately.

Comment: Dear Ankit P.I've tried what you suggest but i still get no results. When i try to output results of "oculto" variable i get no value, is null.

Comment: I hope you are trying to retrieve correct variable ? you question has variable "ocult" and your comment has "oculto" so kindly verify. Also your <aui:input ..> is inside the html form tag ? If still you are facing the issue kindly paste your view.jsp & action class code